# Playing music in the background while another task is running

Tags: vbscript

Sometimes some tasks can be taken a lot of time to end up.
This code is created in order to play a random radio music in background while the script is running another task until to finish up and the music will stop too.

The code is working well, just i'm waiting for any suggestion to improve this code, like to add a progress bar or something else ?
So what do you think ?

```
'**********************************Description in English***********************************
'This vbscript is created by Hackoo on 29/09/2019
'Sometimes some tasks can be taken a lot of time to end up.
'This code is created in order to play music in background while the script is running another
'task until to finish up and the music will stop too.
'So, the user can listen to the music playing while the script is running another task.
'**********************************Description en Français**********************************
'Parfois, certaines tâches peuvent prendre beaucoup de temps pour finir.
'Ceci est créé afin de jouer de la musique en arrière-plan pendant que,
'le script exécute une autre tâche jusqu’à la terminer et la musique s’arrêtera aussi.
'Ainsi, l'utilisateur peut écouter la musique pendant que le script exécute une autre tâche.
'*******************************************************************************************
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "The script is already Running" & vbCrlf &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"The script is already Running"    
    WScript.Quit  
Else
    Call Run_as_Admin()
    Dim Title,EndUP,WS,fso,Temp,WSF_File,URL_Music,CMD,Process_Music,StartTime,Duration
    Title = "Playing music while another task is running by "& Chr(169) &" Hackoo 2019"
    EndUP = False
    Set WS = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    WSF_File = Temp & "\Music.wsf"
    URL_Music = Random_Music
    Call Create_WSF_Music_File()
    CMD = "wscript.exe " & DblQuote(WSF_File) & " //job:PlayMusic "& DblQuote(URL_Music) &""
    Set Process_Music = WS.Exec(cmd)

    WS.Popup "Playing this Radio music "& DblQuote(URL_Music) & vbCrlf &_
    "in the background while the script is running another task until to finish it"_
    ,5,Title,vbInformation + vbSystemModal

    Do While Process_Music.Status = 0
        If EndUP = False Then
'**********************************************************************************************************************
'Your Main Code goes Here
StartTime = Timer
Call RUN_CMD ( _
            "echo.>%Tmp%\LogCMD.txt" &_
            "& (Tracert.exe www.codereview.stackexchange.com" &_
            "& Ping www.codereview.stackexchange.com" &_
            "& Tracert.exe www.google.com" &_
            "& Ping www.google.com" &_
            "& NetStat -abnof)>>%Tmp%\LogCMD.txt" &_
            "& Start /MAX %Tmp%\LogCMD.txt"_
            )

            Duration = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0)
            WS.Popup "The task had taken a run time until its completion about :" & vbCrlf &_
            vbTab & convertTime(Duration) & vbCrlf & _
            vbTab & WScript.ScriptName,10,Title,vbExclamation + vbSystemModal
'**********************************************************************************************************************
        Else
            On Error Resume Next  'to ignore "invalid window handle" errors
            Process_Music.Terminate
            On Error Goto 0
            EndUP = True
        End If
    Loop
End If
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_WSF_Music_File()
    Dim oWSF
    Set oWSF = fso.OpenTextFile(WSF_File,2,True)
    oWSF.WriteLine "<job id=""PlayMusic"">"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "<script language=""Vbscript"">"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Dim URL_Music"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "URL_Music = WScript.Arguments(0)"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Call Play(URL_Music)"
    oWSF.WriteLine "Function Play(URL)"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Dim Sound"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Set Sound = CreateObject(""WMPlayer.OCX"")"               
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Sound.URL = URL"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Sound.settings.volume = 100"                               
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Sound.Controls.play"                                     
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0"                
    oWSF.WriteLine      "wscript.sleep 100"                                       
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Loop"  
    oWSF.WriteLine "End Function"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "</script>"
    oWSF.WriteLine "</job>"
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function RUN_CMD(StrCmd)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell") 
    MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
    Result = ws.run(MyCmd,0,True)
    EndUP = True
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Random_Music()
    Dim URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6,ListMusic,i,j,tmp
    URL1 = "http://94.23.221.158:9197/stream"
    URL2 = "http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
    URL3 = "http://vr-live-mp3-128.scdn.arkena.com/virginradio.mp3"
    URL4 = "http://185.52.127.168/fr/30201/mp3_128.mp3?origine=fluxradios"
    URL5 = "http://icecast.skyrock.net/s/natio_mp3_128k"
    URL6 = "http://185.52.127.173/fr/30601/mp3_128.mp3?origine=tunein"
    ListMusic = array(URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6)
    Randomize
    For i = 0 To UBound(ListMusic)
        j = Int((UBound(ListMusic) - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        tmp = ListMusic(i)
        ListMusic(i) = ListMusic(j)
        ListMusic(j) = tmp
    Next  
    Random_Music=tmp
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function AppPrevInstance()
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")  
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)
        End With
    End With
End Function    
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'" 
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function convertTime(seconds)
    Dim ConvSec,ConvHour,ConvMin
   ConvSec = seconds Mod 60
   If Len(ConvSec) = 1 Then
         ConvSec = "0" & ConvSec
   End If
   ConvMin = (seconds Mod 3600) \ 60
   If Len(ConvMin) = 1 Then
         ConvMin = "0" & ConvMin
   End If
   ConvHour =  seconds \ 3600
   If Len(ConvHour) = 1 Then
         ConvHour = "0" & ConvHour
   End If
   convertTime = ConvHour & ":" & ConvMin & ":" & ConvSec
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Run_as_Admin()
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
   CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute DblQuote(WScript.FullName) _
   , DblQuote(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In `Random_Music`, perhaps you can save the last played URL in the Registry and avoid the 1 out of 6 chance of playing the same URL twice in a row. Without randomizing it you could simply go down your list of URLs by saving such a variable.